# Using python to parse a log file into csv with formatting

Tags: python

I attempted this problem using PowerShell but couldn't get it to work so I've returned to python to attempt it. I currently have my headers being written to a csv file however I'm having trouble trying to figure out how I would extract specific information from the logfile that I want. I only need the data points as I no longer need the headers from it.

What I have so far:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

header = np.asarray([["Connection","IKE PEER","TYPE","REKEY","ENCRYPT","AUTH","ROLE","STATE","HASH","LIFETIME","LIFETIME REMAINING"]])
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
mywriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
mywriter.writerows(header)
```

An example of what I need to parse to a csv file:

```
1   IKE Peer: 184.188.106.30 (PHX2)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : 3des            Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 86400
    Lifetime Remaining: 52140
2   IKE Peer: 96.39.70.182 (Worcester)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 28800
    Lifetime Remaining: 5929
3   IKE Peer: 162.17.89.105 (Fresno)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 28800
    Lifetime Remaining: 6564
4   IKE Peer: 68.255.155.73 (San Leandro)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : 3des            Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 86400
    Lifetime Remaining: 71608
5   IKE Peer: 96.69.172.213 (Denver WHSE)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 86400
    Lifetime Remaining: 35956
6   IKE Peer: 75.146.82.217 (Nashville)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 86400
    Lifetime Remaining: 72546
7   IKE Peer: 172.95.3.46 (Manteca)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 28800
    Lifetime Remaining: 15891
8   IKE Peer: 76.79.100.162 (Anaheim)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 28800
    Lifetime Remaining: 18567
9   IKE Peer: 69.75.17.212 (Murrieta)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 86400
    Lifetime Remaining: 78551
10  IKE Peer: 64.183.136.234 (Coeur D'Alene)
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE 
    Encrypt : aes-256         Hash    : SHA       
    Auth    : preshared       Lifetime: 28800
    Lifetime Remaining: 21253
```

What I want the CSV file to look like but with more data points underneath.
[image]

Thanks A lot!

Comment: You might consider using [pyparsing](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html) to read this structured data, then you can write out the csv however you'd like.

Comment: I should have been more clear. What I meant was that I need the headers but I just wanted the data points from the log file instead of the words like IKE PEER.

Comment: I've added an edit to show what I wanted the CSV file to look like.

Comment: As an aside, there is no good reason to use `numpy` here and you shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kind of brute force but worked with sample.

https://onlinegdb.com/cJoLkXtzi9

```py
import csv

header = ["Connection","IKE PEER","TYPE","REKEY","ENCRYPT","AUTH","ROLE","STATE","HASH","LIFETIME","LIFETIME REMAINING"]
with (
    open('output.csv', 'w') as f,
    open('log.txt', 'r') as file
    ):
    mywriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    mywriter.writerow(header)
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in range(0, len(lines), 6):
        conn, ike, peer, *ip = lines[line].split()
        row = lines[line+1].split()
        typ, role = row[2], row[5]
        row = lines[line+2].split()
        key, stat = row[2], row[5]
        row = lines[line+3].split()
        enc, has = row[2], row[5]
        row = lines[line+4].split()
        auth, life = row[2], row[4]
        rem = lines[line+5].split()[2]
        ip = ' '.join(ip)
        row = [conn, ip, typ, key, enc, auth, role, stat, has, life, rem]
        mywriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `' '.join(i for i in ip)` -> `''.join(ip)`. in general, `[x for x in whatever]` should just be `whatever`

Comment: I quite like this way as I can mostly understand it. Could you explain the choice of row[2], and row[5] when you are selecting the information. Is that just the area of where the info would be?

Comment: Also currently running into a problem where the output to the csv file is skipping every other line. You wouldn't happen to be encountering the same issue?

Comment: @richard just to notify

Comment: the row is split into a list of words and `row[x]` assigns index x to a variable.  that way if the word length is variable you don't miss anything versus slicing a string at specific indexes.

`csv` recommends opening files with `newline=''` argument. try `open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a while loop and process lines "6 at a time" you might be able to leverage the fix nature of the rows to pick out your data:

```py
import csv

headers = ["Connection","IKE PEER","TYPE","REKEY","ENCRYPT","AUTH","ROLE","STATE","HASH","LIFETIME","LIFETIME REMAINING"]
with open("fileout.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as file_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    with open("infile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as log_file:
        while True:
            try:
                line = next(log_file)
            except StopIteration:
                break

            new_row = {}
            new_row["Connection"] = line[:4].strip()
            new_row["IKE PEER"] = line[14:].strip()

            line = next(log_file)
            new_row["TYPE"] = line[14:30].strip()
            new_row["ROLE"] = line[40:].strip()

            line = next(log_file)
            new_row["REKEY"] = line[14:30].strip()
            new_row["STATE"] = line[40:].strip()

            line = next(log_file)
            new_row["ENCRYPT"] = line[14:30].strip()
            new_row["HASH"] = line[40:].strip()

            line = next(log_file)
            new_row["AUTH"] = line[14:30].strip()
            new_row["LIFETIME"] = line[40:].strip()

            line = next(log_file)
            new_row["LIFETIME REMAINING"] = line[24:].strip()

            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Hi this actually mostly works for what I need it. However when I run it I encounter an error `Exception has occurred: StopIteration
exception: no description
  File "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\AnotherTestFile for Parsing Log file.py", line 30, in <module>
    line = next(log_file)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
StopIteration: `

Comment: But it does build the csv file very nicely although there a few formatting issues. Thank you very much. Im gonna try to figure this out a bit more.